# How to force window focus of Terminator after it is launched with --new-tab as command line argument?

Tags: gnome, terminator

I'm using Terminator.

My goal is to press ctrl-alt-T, and get a new tab in Terminator, and have that instance of Terminator get focus (like what happens with existing ctrl-alt-T to default Terminal)

Command used is:

terminator --new-tab

The problem is that the new tab opens, but no focus.  That existing window could be anywhere.

There doesn't seem to be a command line argument to force Terminator to get focus after it's launched.

Is there a way to do so?

One potential avenue might be supplying -r to set WM_WINDOW_ROLE, and then a linux command to force that role to get focus? I cannot find such a command however.

Thanks.

Comment: What desktop are you using? In the default desktop, ctrl-alt-T does *not*  give an existing window focus, but instead always launches a new window.

Comment: For me it launches a new terminal, and that terminal then has focus, so you can type away.   Default desktop.

Comment: OK, that is normal behavior. So your problem is that the command for terminator (which you do not provide, so it is very hard to test) does create a new tab in a running window, but that window does not get keyboard focus?

Comment: Updated with command run.  That's exactly correct, yes.  And not being able to just type into the new console is quite irritating of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Install the Gnome Shell extension [NoAnnoyance v2](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2182/noannoyance/) by bjoerndaase.
- If you wish to keep the default focus behavior of Gnome Shell, you can install the extension [Run or raise](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1336/run-or-raise/) by e2rd, and define the following shortcut:

  ```
  <Ctrl><Alt>i:always-run,terminator --new-tab,terminator,
  ```
- Alternatively, there are some Gnome Shell extensions that expose a dbus interface that can be accessed from the command line. You can then define the shortcut key through the regular "Settings" - "Keyboard", and after the command `terminator --new-tab`, the dbus interface is used to bring the terminator window to the foreground. Some extensions allow for such approach, e.g. [Activate Window By Title](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5021/activate-window-by-title/) by lucaswerkmeister, [Window Calls](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4724/window-calls/) by domandoman and  [Window Calls Extended](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4974/window-calls-extended/) by hseliger.
- On Xorg only, however working in any desktop environment, the command `wmctrl -x -a terminator` can be used to bring the window in focus.
- [`jumpapp`](https://github.com/mkropat/jumpapp), essentially a powerfull bash script that relies on `wmctrl`, can do this with a single command using the "Argument Passthrough (-p option)": `jumpapp -c terminator -p terminator --new-tab`.

Comment: Thanks, but this review sounds ominous....

"I was hoping for an extension which ensures that windows created by user events, such as starting an application or opening a save dialog, do not open under other windows.

This does that, but also does something which is actually more annoying than windows popping up under other windows: it causes all applications to steal focus whenever they have an alert. Whatever you were typing? You are now typing it into whatever messaging app you just got a message on.
"

Comment: I added some more options.

Comment: the wmctrl option looks like it could work, by calling a script that first launches terminator, then runs wmctrl, targetting that role.  I've just bumped into KDE Plasma,which has made this trivial to fix also, so I'm switching to that instead (for other reasons also).   Thanks for your help.